# Install specific QGIS version (3.16.10) in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux, ubuntugis

I want to install in my Ubuntu 20.04 version specific QGIS version (3.16.10).

After reading this [QGIS Installers](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) I realize (maybe wrong) is the possibility to install only specific versions (latest version, latest ltr version and master dev version).
In the Repositories tab in the link don't have information how to install previous version (I want to install version 3.16.10).

Any idea how to install QGIS Version 3.16.10 in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to build the software from its source code.

Source code of tagged releases is available here on github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/releases (e.g. [3.16.10](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/releases?q=3.16.10&expanded=true))

Build instructions are given in the so called "building guide": https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL.md

If you follow these carefully, step by step, you should be able to build the software yourself.

Don't hesitate to make use of [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) in Ubuntu in order to make your package manager "aware" of your custom installation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only way is to build it by yourself from sources. See instructions here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL.md

You can choose then every single version you want.